# Elasticsearch shuts down automatically - Ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch, digital-ocean

I am using a VM instance running Ubuntu (1GB RAM + 25GB Harddisk) with Elasticsearch on it. Although I have managed to install the elasticsearch on it when i start the service via `sudo service elasticsearch start` the ES service starts and then stops after few seconds. Throwing following error 
[image]

TIA

Comment: Did you changed the default memory allocation? 
By default it sets 1GB, so if you have 1GB on your VM it will not be able to run.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html

Comment: Also check elasticsearch logs. If JVM is even trying to start, it would have posted some error messages.

Comment: May you please specify your Elasticsearch, java and Ubuntu versions? Please show the output of `java -version`.

Comment: did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, ElasticSearch was shutting down due to a lack of memory.

As in my VPS I only have 2G and I can't [use swap](https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/), I changed my `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` to use 300Mb instead of 1G..

```
-Xms300m
-Xmx300m
```

Just restart the service after changing it, and you shoud be good (for a while). :)

Answer (score 0):

An es node default needs 1 gb ram. You give 1 gb ram to ubuntu thats why you get an error. Give more ram to os, or manipulate jvm configs. Read the below link.

> **https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/important-settings.html#heap-size-settings**